# Refreshing <div> and load data from php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I have  on my page and there is a  tag where is some  and values filled from mySQL DB. I need some JavaScript I think. When I select one option, I want to display in this  propriate DATAs which are in DB. without refreshing whole page.
Can you tell me how to do it, if you know that please?:)

```
<div id="country1" class="tabcontent">
<label>Choose protocol</label>
<SELECT name="cisloprot">
<?php




$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123456");
$sql = "SELECT kod FROM prot GROUP BY kod";

$rs = mysql_query($sql,$con);


while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{

echo "<OPTION VALUE=".$r['kod'].">".$r['kod']."</OPTION>";
}

?>
</SELECT>

</div>
```

Comment: No page refresh? You need Ajax.

Comment: Question is vague. Do you want to refresh this drop down when another button or option is selected in the page?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you will need some JavaScript for that - I suggest you [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library for that. The best choice for doing this is [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) which is pretty easy to understand and use for those things.

[There](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp) is a example for doing this with JavaScript only and [there](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp) if you are doing this with jQuery. And full tutorial on connecting PHP with JavaScript is [there](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-jquery-ajax/index.html).